# How to convert from a Label to a string using FindControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to convert this Label to a string but it seems to be null.   Here is the error message: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_2zs3gdg3.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Label myDentistName = (Label)item.FindControl("Dentist.Dentist_Name");
sDentistName = myDentistName.Text;
Session["DentistName"] = sDentistName;
```

and this is how it is define in the `.aspx`

```
<td>
   <asp:Label ID="dentistNameLabel" runat="server" 
        Text='<%# Eval("Dentist.Dentist_Name") %>' />
</td>
```

The dentist name is properly display on the screen.

Comment: Are you sure `item.FindControl` doesn't return null?

Comment: @Selman22 yes it return null but on the screen I am seeing the DentistName

Comment: @user3127986: Yes, but you're looking for a control with an ID of "Dentist.Dentist_Name" - look at the ID of the control you really want...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the ID of the Label control.

```
Label myDentistName = (Label)item.FindControl("dentistNameLabel");
```

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be this:

```
Label myDentistName = (Label)item.FindControl("dentistNameLabel");
```

Answer (score 1):

`Page.FindControl` method takes element `id` as parameter, see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

So you need to pass it element `id` which is `dentistNameLabel`.

```
Label myDentistName = (Label)item.FindControl("dentistNameLabel");
```